# Difference between override onCreate and nothing to do in subclass?

Tags: java

BaseClass A:

```
public class A extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

SubClass B1:

```
public class B1 extends A {

}
```

SubClass B2:

```
public class B2 extends A {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

As code, any difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: No, so you have no reason to override onCreate in class B.

Comment: There are no differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"B2" will execute `B`'s `onCreate`, which will execute `A`'s on create.

"B1" will execute `A`'s `onCreate`.

The end result would be the same.

Of course, if all `A`'s `onCreate` does is call `Activity`'s `onCreate`, you don't have to override `onCreate` in `A` either.

Comment: if A is Application, not Activity, the same result in run-time?

Comment: @Kid This behavior is not specific to sub-classes of Activity. It is the way method overriding behaves in general. If a sub-class overrides a super-class method and only calls the super class implementation without adding any logic, it doesn't have to override that method in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**No. Here is a really good visual way to think about this problem.**

[image]

Here, you can see that:

```
Domino 1 -> Domino 2 -> Domino 3 -> ETC
```

Now, I can push domino one, and still get to the very last domino. **OR, I can push domino 2, and still get to the very last domino. AT THE END, WE STILL GET TO THE LAST DOMINO**

Think of it like a chain reaction.

```
B2 -> B -> A
```

At the end you are at A

```
B1 -> A
```

At the end you are at A

So, at the end, they are the same. One may take a tiny bit longer though...

[image]

**In this diagram, class E is the same as class B, because at the end, they all extend class A. This is if, like in your scenario, they all have the same methods.**

Answer (score 0):

Result will be same. There is no use of calling only super class method from overridden method. It doesnt make any sense